# Trying to identify Star Wars LEGO set

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I bought a second hand LEGO set and it came with a box of loose ends, with some partially built sets. I think this is a Star Wars set - any help in identifying it would be welcomed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be [Mace Windu's Jedi Starfighter (7868)](https://brickset.com/sets/7868-1/Mace-Windu-s-Jedi-Starfighter):

[image: ship photo]

The [instructions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/4642654.pdf) are available on LEGO.com if you want to try to make it complete.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much

Comment: @Scooby if you're satisfied with this answer it is good to click the check box beside the answer so it is considered "accepted".